# How to use latexmk in Windows with MikTex and Winedt

Tags: miktex, latexmk, winedt

I am using Windows 7 x64 with MikTex and WinEdt. I just found latexmk has the function for continuous preview when we type latex document. I would like to know if this works if I type my latex document with WinEdt? I didn't read the manual carefully, but I don't know where I shoud add this command `latexmk -pvc -pdf foo`. Also, should I try to find a way for auto saving the changed document in order to make latexmk work?

Comment: I have found that I have installed latexmk when I installed and updated my MikTeX 2.9. But still don't know how to add this command `latexmk -pvc -pdf foo`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to run latexmk in its continuous preview mode is to start a command window, change directory to where the LaTeX document is, and then type in the command `latexmk -pvc -pdf foo`.  Then latexmk will run continuously, regularly checking the source files for changes.  To stop it, either type a <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or close the command window.

Possibly there's a way of doing this directly from WinEdt, but an expert on WinEdt would need to tell you about that.  It is also possible to set up a file association in Windows so that you can right-click on an icon for the LaTeX file and get the above command run; but I don't have a Windows 7 computer to work out the instructions.

There's no need for autosaving the file.  Manual saving is better.  With the above command, latexmk will compile your document shortly after you save a changed source file.  (An autosave is liable to save your file in the middle of the typing of a LaTeX command, which will result in an error in the compilation, and that will probably be excessively annoying.)

Comment: Another approach to achieve continuous compiling is to use latexdameon. See http://william.famille-blum.org/software/latexdaemon/index.html for more details. It can be used with pdflatex, latex, and latex>dvips>ps2pdf.